# Determine size of UART software input buffer on microblaze soft-cpu

Tags: linux, usart

I need to know the size of the USART input buffer on a Microblaze uclinux. I can access a very reduced BusyBox v1.23.2
I don't know if the buffer is implemented in HW (FPGA), SW or both but I can receive more than 20 Bytes in one non-blocking read attempt. 
So how or where can I get the buffer size? 
Why? I am implementing a FIFO buffer structure for my C code and want to have the buffer size in a realistic range (not too large / small)

Comment: Open the serial terminal device while it is receiving data.  Repeatedly call the FIONREAD **ioctl()** to get the number of bytes in the input buffer.  The number should max out when buffer overrun occurs.  But your reasoning for this number makes no sense.  Your buffer sizes should be dictated by message size, rather than previous buffers.